# Serenity: How to hide Test Data from Report?

Tags: java, reporting, data-driven-tests, serenity-bdd, thucydides

Is there any way to hide Test Data section in report for data driven tests?
By default this block is called "Examples:".
I use HashMap as input for every test and it looks like the whole my HashMap is printed out as String in this Section.
So, because this section is leading - for many tests it becomes just a Huge piece of text.

Maybe there is a way to printOut just some item from test data, not the whole map?

@Qualifier works only for Test Names

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can't turn off the Examples table in the current versions. You could wrap your HashMap into a more domain-specific class, and then override the toString() method.